# Embedded MongoDb Insertion using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am inserting data using node js into mongodb, but it have encountered with an error

> Syntax Error Unexpected token.

it will accepting value from front end and save data in backend. 
The req.params.score accepting the value from front end.

Please can any one can help?

1).            MongoDb Schema

```
       var userScore = new Schema({
        child: {
     quiz_level:{
         current_level:{type:Number},
        level_attempted:{type:Array,
            level_id:{type:Number},
            level_complete:{type:Boolean},
            level_score:{type:Number}
               }
                }
                  }
                  });
```

2).              Node js

```
try{

        var userObj = {

        child.quiz_level.level_attempted.level_score:req.params.score

        };

        var user = new levelScoreQuiz(userObj);

        user.save(function(err, result)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                console.log('Error While Saving the reuslt ' +err)}
            else
            {
            console.log("User score saved successfully");
            res.json(result);
            }
         });

        }
        catch(err)
        {
        console.log('Error While Saving the reuslt ' +err);
        return next(err);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var userObj = {

    "child.quiz_level.level_attempted.level_score": req.params.score

};
```

Try that, I had a similar problem earlier in the week and passing the object property as a string seemed to work.